# Работа с текстовым файлом в python: поиск полной строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я открываю текстовый файл и заношу в переменную все его значения имеющие такой вид

> aaa:bbbbbb
>
> cccc:www
>
> ww:gg

Как мне реализовать проверку, содержит ли этот документ точное значение (aaa:bbbbbb)? Пробовал через .find() и через if .. in ..., но при вводе, к примеру a:b - возвращает != -1, а должно работать только если вся строка содержит именно такое значение, которое было введено. Подскажите, как это сделать?

```
def login(login, password):
    logins = open('logins.txt', 'r')
    logins = logins.read()
    logpass = login + ":" + password
    if logins.find(logpass) != -1:
         return 1
    else:
         return 0
```

Comment: Проверяется содержание последовательности в строке, или всем файле?

Comment: Добавил скрин, по сути - во всем файле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто, считав файл, преобразовать полученную строку в список, где каждая строка файла является элементом списка, и проверять есть ли требуемая комбинация в списке.

```
def login(login, password):
    with open("logins.txt", "r") as file:
        logins = file.read().split()
    logpass = login + ":" + password
    return logpass in logins
```

Comment: Это работает для примера в вопросе, но не найдёт полную строку в общем случае, когда пробел внутри строки может быть.

Comment: @jfs Тогда можно использовать `split('\n')`.

Comment: @kff - да, лучше так - предлагаю Вам поправить свой ответ, тем более, что человек его принял

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы проверить содержит ли входной файл заданную строку целиком:

```
line = "aaa:bbbb"
with open(filename) as file:
    if line in map(str.strip, file):
        print("{line} is in {filename}".format(**vars()))
```

Код игнорирует пробелы в начале/конце каждой строки.

Код работает потому что file является итератором над строками (разделёнными "\n") в Питоне.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_logpass(*login_password: (str, str), file='logins.txt') -> bool:
    logpass = ':'.join(login_password)
    with open(file) as f:
        return any(logpass in line for line in f)

is_logpass('aaa', 'bbbbbb')
```

Comment: этот код имеет ту же проблему, что и код в вопросе: он может найти часть строки: `a:b`, вместо строки целиком.